# How to make csc.exe C# 6 aware

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0, csc

I am compiling a basic console app using :

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:exe /out:myapp.exe Program.cs
```

Which first prints :

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1038.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Then fails because I am using string interpolation like `$"{x}"`. The error is:

```
error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'
```

I assume this is because the `csc.exe` does not understand `C# 6`. How do I make this compiler `C# 6` aware?

Answer (score 7):

You are using an old version of the compiler. From [this MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9959d4c1-16fe-45bc-9535-7b0775d26e9a/please-confirm-c-60-compiler-is-not-installed-with-net-framework-46-if-so-location?forum=csharpgeneral), the C# compiler is no longer part of the .NET Framework. You have to download it yourself.

You can do that from this NuGet statement:

```
nuget install Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

Comment: wow, is it possible to install this on to a system without VS? Part of the reason I was using csc.exe was so that I did'nt have to touch VS.

Comment: Yes, download the nuget package manager. The link is in that forum post.

Comment: The "current version" is also bundled under C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin if you've installed the Build Tools package.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem here;

I fixed using the Roslyn compiler inside de Visual Studio 2019 instalation folder , setting up the environment variable of csc to it.

Changed

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

To

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
```

In the system environment variables and worked here